# My Bitcoin Core wallet does not receive BTC

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, withdrawal, bitstamp

My Bitcoin Core wallet did not receive BTCs; it is already syncronized.
The transaction was submitted from Bitstamp on the 18th of July, as withdrawal.
In Bitcoin Core I selected the receive button, then I copied the address in Bitstamp withdrawal, then I submitted the transaction.
In Bitstamp everything appears to be ok, the amount has been transferred.
Ok but transferred where? In Bitcoin Core nothing arrived ...
Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have the hash of the transaction?

Comment: yes: e8efdf4663db5f8d5139e3c2ae684fc9072a89da

Comment: Thats's not the full hash, it's too short

Comment: may be he is asking about https://blockchain.info/address/1NEf87g56TMDJLUs9JfXzyenz2EUUSMqj1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Blockchain, you transferred 0.01 bitcoins to the address `1NEf87g56TMDJLUs9JfXzyenz2EUUSMqj1`

If you can see this Bitcoin address in Bitcoin Core wallet (Menu File > Receiving addresses) and Core is fully synchronized then something is wrong, as this shouldn't happen (see below). If you can't see this address, maybe you created/opened a different wallet and then you need to open the correct wallet, containing this address.

You could try to **re-scan** the blockchain for missed transactions, that is transactions that don't appear in Core. Exit Core completely (Menu File > Exit), wait for the program to exit and then start it by adding the command line option `-rescan` This might take a long time, depending on the speed of your computer and hard disk.